# alias commands in qsub

Tags: linux, bash, qsub, sungridengine

The -V option with qusb only importing the environment variable but not the alias from .bashrc . For example

```
### in .bashrc
alias ll='ls -ltr'
alias la='ls -A'
export PYTHONPATH=/local/python_other:$PYTHONPATH
```

and the qsub script is

```
#!/bin/sh    
#$ -V
echo $PYTHONPATH
ls
ll
la
```

In this case `echo $PYTHONPATH` and `ls` works fine but `ll` and `la` gives error `ll: command not found` .
So how to import the alias commands in qsub ?

OR is there any better alternative to `alias` so that commands (`ll` or `la`) behave like `ls` and can be easily imported

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are intended to be command-line conveniences. They are not well-suited for use in scripting. For most purposes, you should use functions. Functions can be exported to child Bash scripts, but not likely to other environments.

That said, you can try explicitly sourcing your `~/.bashrc` in your qsub script.

```
. $HOME/.bashrc
```

or

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

I don't know which of these is supported by qsub.

Answer (score 1):

`~/.bashrc` is not interpreted if you run a script not in an interactive mode.
You must switch the interactive mode on

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```

or better just import `~/.bashrc` explicitly at the beginning of the script:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```